# Transpose to excel from JSON how to round up?

Tags: json, excel, transpose, percentage

i have the excel script and the jason page, to not make this huge im just going to place the important things.

```
function pull(toonName,toonRealm) {

  if(!toonName || !toonRealm) {
   return ""
  }

  var toonJSON = UrlFetchApp.fetch("us.battle.net/api/wow/character/"+toonRealm+"/"+toonName+"?fields=items,talents,statistics,stats,progression,audit") 
  var toon = JSON.parse(toonJSON.getContentText())

var getStats = function(sta) {
    var crit = sta.crit,
        haste = sta.haste,
        mastery = sta.mastery,
        spirit = sta.spr,
        multi = sta.multistrike,
        vers = sta.versatilityDamageDoneBonus
    return [crit, haste, mastery, spirit, multi, vers]
  }
  var Stats = getStats(toon.stats) 

var toonInfo = new Array(Stats[0], Stats[1], Stats[2], Stats[4], Stats[5], Stats[3]
      )
 return toonInfo;
}
```

what i got is a number with a lot of decimals for example: 15.154545, 12.566666, 19.97091.

and what i want is to convert that to: 15.15% 12.56% 19.97%

either from the script or from the excel.

The thing is that when i try to convert that from excel selecting the number format of %, it gives me: 1515.45%, 1256.66%, 1997.09%

but if i chose the number format it gives me the 15.15, 12.56 (w/o the "%")

and when i tried to inject that form the script like:

```
var toonInfo = new Array(Stats[0]+"%", Stats[1]+"%", Stats[2]+"%", Stats[4]+"%", Stats[5]+"%", Stats[3]
```

excel couldnt edit the numbers.So maby this is a dumb question but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: internally, excel would store `15.5%` as `0.155`. if you stuff 15.5 into a field and tell Excel to display it as a %, then Excel's going to do 15.5*100...

Comment: This ^ Instead of adding the percentage sign (which excel will store as a string), why not multiply the value by `.01` and THEN set the number format to percentage. http://i.imgur.com/SrDUCTy.png

Comment: Another option is now edited in my answer. It may be the best way. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the number format to `0.0\%`

If you want to display two decimal places after the percentage, use `0.00\%` instead.

Credit: http://jolleytrails.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-add-percentage-sign-without.html

Alternatively, add this after you initialize toonInfo

```
for(var i=0; i<toonInfo.length; i++) {
    toonInfo[i] *= .01;
}
```

Then set the number format to percentage when storing in excel.

[image]